# R ビュフォンの針の問題について(確認)

Tags: r

Rを用いてビュフォンの針の問題をプログラミングしたのですが、実行したところ正しいのかどうかわかりませんでした。（おそらく正しいとは思うものの、確認させていただきます。）

とりあえず、私は以下のようにプログラムをしました。

```
> buffon<-function(n){
  L<-1
  P<-2
  count<-0
  for(i in c(1:n)){
   x<-runif(1,0,P/2)
   theta<-runif(1,0,pi/2)
  if(x<P/2){
  if((sin(theta)*L/2)>x)  count<-count+1
  }
  else{
  if((sin(theta)*L/2)<x)  count<-count+1
  }
  }
 p<-2*L*n/(P*count)
 p
}
```

実行結果

```
> buffon(10)
[1] 5
> buffon(100)
[1] 3.846154
> buffon(1000)
[1] 3.215434
> buffon(10000)
[1] 3.072197
> buffon(100000)
[1] 3.138535
> buffon(1000000)
[1] 3.143478
> buffon(10000000)
[1] 3.142044
```

ビュフォンの針の問題で求めるのは、円周率の近似値なので、正しいとは思うのですが、Rを始めてからまだ一か月足らずの未熟者で、不安なので一応確認させていただきます。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x<-runif(1,0,P/2)` としていますので(`x: [0, P/2]`)、`if(x<P/2)` の分岐は必要ないかと思います。
ところで、R では vector での計算が可能ですので、以下の様にも書くことができます。

```r
buffon <- function(n) {
  L <- 1; P <- 2
  x <- runif(n, 0, P/2)
  proj <- sin(runif(n, 0, pi/2))*L/2
  2*L*n/(P*sum(proj > x))
}

for(n in 10^c(1:8)) {
  cat(sprintf("n = %9d, %f\n", n, buffon(n)))
}

n =        10, 10.000000
n =       100, 2.857143
n =      1000, 3.115265
n =     10000, 3.138732
n =    100000, 3.124219
n =   1000000, 3.140556
n =  10000000, 3.139620
n = 100000000, 3.142656
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。参考にさせていただきます。